# Using the .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to use jQuery's `.load()` or `.get()` functions to replace AJAX, I've got this:

```
var counter = 0;
timeInterval(changeStock(counter), 2000);

function changeStock(number) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=number')
    counter++;
    if (counter == <? php echo $count1; ?> ) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
```

But nothing is coming up. Any ideas?? My `<div id="stocks">` is fine it seems..

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @f-calderan Its a stocks idea. It should get data from stock.php depending on the parameter then display it. then two seconds later, it should change to the next stock in the array on stock.php. stock.php is working fine

Comment: oh god, sometimes its the obvious things

Comment: if `timeInterval` is `setInterval` then it should be passed a reference to a function, not the result of it, so `setInterval(changeStock, 2000);` would do (since counter is global). Also, you would want `changeStock` to actually perform the request, not just repeatedly set it to perform once on DOMReady.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few incorrect lines in your script :

```
timeInterval(changeStock(counter), 2000);
```

should probably be `setInterval()`

```
$('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=number')
```

should be `$('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol='+number)`

and `$(document).ready(function() {})` within in a function ?!?!?!

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var counter = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    $('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=' + counter, function () {
      counter++;
      if (counter == <? php echo $count1; ?> ) {
        counter = 0;
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

This will execute the inner function each 2000 milliseconds - the function will load the url (passing the counter as a parameter) and then executing the callback function - which increments the counts and checks if it equals whatever is in `$count1`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass `number` as a parameter to `load`, not a string.

```
$('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=' + number);
```

Also, i assume you want to update your counter in a success callback:

```
$('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=' + number, function () {
    counter++;

    if (counter == <? php echo $count1; ?> ) {
        counter = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: its not this because if it was this, the stock.php would respond invalid stock symbol. but it is a mistake I accept that, but not the actual one

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `setInterval` where you have written `timeInterval`.
And you probably wanted to have

```
$('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=' + number);
```

Also is this file is parsed by php? because of the `<? php echo $count1; ?>` if its .js it probably isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You have an syntax error ";" is missed:

```
    $('#stocks').load('/stock.php?symbol=number')
```

jQuery not show errors by default, so it seems like nothing happens.

Comment: This is entirely unrelated and misconceived.

Comment: `;` is not required in JavaScript